# Postgres. Lock Monitoring all databases with name in relation field

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible using queries to check the locks of all databases so that table names are in the relation field?
I'm using next queries  https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring,
but in the relation field not table names.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that isn't so, you can see locks from other databases.  But you can't translate the object numbers from other databases to have meaningful names.

Comment: thanks. how i understand my need turn on log log_lock_waits for more information